# How to refer to a specific decade in Spanish? eg. the 1960's

Tags: traducción, tiempo

In English, when you want to refer to a specific decade you simply pluralize the year:

> the nineteen-sixties (written 1960's) OR the nineteen-tens (written 1910's)

Granted, referring to the first decade of a century is sometimes difficult this way. The nineteen-hundreds (1900's) is usually taken to mean 1900-1999 and not 1900-1909, but that's a separate question.

How you refer to a specific decade in Spanish? I would predict 'La década de mil-novecientos-sesenta', but I'm probably wrong. Also, how is this abbreviated in numerical written form, like 'the 1960's'? Are there any slang terms that would be the equivalent of saying 'the sixties' or 'the eighties' in English?

Comment: You can translate "the '60s" as "los años sesenta" but on the net I also find "los sesentas".

Answer (score 4):

You refer to a specific decade in Spanish like this:

The nineteen-sixties (written 1960's):

- Los sesenta
- La década de los sesenta
- Los años sesenta

> Granted, referring to the first decade of a century is sometimes
>   difficult this way. The nineteen-hundreds (1900's) is usually taken to
>   mean 1900-1999 and not 1900-1909, but that's a separate question.

There is no widely-used expression in Spanish to refer to the first decade of the century. `Años diez` is not commonly used but you can use sentences like:

- Primera década del siglo
- Comienzos de siglo
- Principios de siglo
- Los primeros diez años del siglo

Comment: +1, for this is a complete but succinct answer.

Comment: Las normas de estilo de Wikipedia (que sé que no fueron inventadas pero desconozco la fuente original) recomiendan escribir _«los años 1960»_.  Creo que es una buena recomendación en la escritura pues evita ambigüedad aunque suena un poco artificioso en el habla.  Creo que debería incluirse.

Comment: ¿Tienes por ahí el enlace para documentarlo? y edito la entrada

Comment: Como recomendación me parece correcto lo que dice Wikipedia, pero con motivo de entender a un español nativo recomendaría el término "los sesenta" o  "los años sesenta", pues es el más usado.

Answer (score 2):

Well it seems that the **[RAE](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltConsulta?lema=d%C3%A9cada)** says that the fomulation with an **s** (1920s) is outright incorrect in Spanish, and that it shoulnd't be used only because it is used in English.

It explains that when you refer to a decade in Spanish you are explicitly referring to all 10 years 1920-1929 inclusive as an example.

They say that you should say it in the following manner:

> For 1960:
>
> 1. En la década de los sesenta del siglo XX [...]
> 2. En los años sesenta del último siglo [...]

I didn't know it wasn't allowed to use the formulation 1920's or 1920s. Although in many hispanic countries it is widely understood because of its use in English. So you are probably safe using it with the apostrophe.

Here the orignial text:

> <sub>década. 1. Los términos década y decenio significan, ambos,
>   ‘período de diez años consecutivos’; pero mientras que decenio se usa
>   para designar el período de diez años comprendido entre dos años
>   cualesquiera, década designa en especial el período de diez años
>   referido a cada una de las decenas del siglo (años diez, veinte,
>   treinta, etc.). Es muy frecuente expresar los decenios tomando como
>   límites años que terminan en la misma cifra: «El fecundo decenio
>   andaluz (1578-1588) se interrumpió cuando [...] tuvo que trasladarse a
>   Segovia» (Abc [Esp.] 13.12.91); pero hay que saber que esta costumbre
>   implica una inexactitud, ya que esos límites comprenden, en realidad,
>   once años y no diez, pues en el cómputo se incluye tanto el primer año
>   como el último. Se recomienda mayor precisión en la indicación de los
>   decenios, como se ejemplifica a continuación: «El carácter brillante y
>   apolíneo del decenio operístico, 1775-1784, del compositor» (País
>   [Esp.] 1.12.87).</sub>
>
> <sub>2. En cuanto a las diez décadas de cada siglo, cada una de ellas comienza en un año acabado en 1 y termina en un año acabado en 0; así,
>   la primera década del siglo xx es la que va de 1901 a 1910; la
>   segunda, de 1911 a 1920; la tercera, de 1921 a 1930, etc.</sub>
>
> <sub>Es habitual utilizar expresiones como los años veinte, la década
>   de los treinta, los cuarenta, etc., referidas a los decenios que
>   comprenden los años de cada siglo que tienen la misma cifra en su
>   decena; así, la expresión los años veinte alude conjuntamente a los
>   años comprendidos entre 1920 y 1929, ambos inclusive. En estos casos,
>   se desaconseja poner en plural el cardinal referido a la decena: Marca
>   de incorrección.«A través de los veintes y de los treintas, muchos
>   poetas de talento [...] trabajaban en otros estilos» (Hora [Guat.]
>   14.7.97). Tampoco deben usarse fórmulas como Marca de incorrección.los 20s o Marca de incorrección.los 20’s, copiadas del inglés. En el
>   español de América, en la construcción la década de..., aparece a
>   veces en singular el artículo que acompaña al cardinal: la década del
>   treinta, en lugar de la década de los treinta, construcción esta
>   última más habitual y recomendable.</sub>