# ¿Es correcto usar '80 u 80s para referirnos a décadas?

Tags: gramática, ortografía, tiempo

Leyendo [una espléndida respuesta de Rafael](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21800/1674) observé que habla de:

> A consecuencia de lo anterior, resulta razonable pensar que en los **'80** la pregunta diera mucho menos lugar a dudas.
>    <sub>cambio las negritas originales para destacar lo que me generó la duda</sub>

Es decir, utiliza *'80* para referirse a los años que van de 1980 a 1989.

¿Es correcto usarlo? ¿Y es correcto usar 1980's o 1980s tal y como [se preguntó en el pasado](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1954/1674)?

Comment: Creo esta pregunta porque esta información estaba poco encontrable en el sitio y tenía mal SEO. Marcadla como duplicada si así lo consideráis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### No.

Tal y como comenta el Diccionario panhispánico de dudas en su artículo [*década*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=B6fTYMuWLD6udxJmRF):

> Es habitual utilizar expresiones como *los años veinte*, *la década de los treinta*, *los cuarenta*, etc., referidas a los decenios que comprenden los años de cada siglo que tienen la misma cifra en su decena; así, la expresión *los años veinte* alude conjuntamente a los años comprendidos entre 1920 y 1929, ambos inclusive. En estos casos, se desaconseja poner en plural el cardinal referido a la decena: ⓧ«*A través de los veintes y de los treintas, muchos poetas de talento [...] trabajaban en otros estilos*» (Hora [Guat.] 14.7.97). Tampoco deben usarse fórmulas como ⓧ*los 20s* o ⓧ*los 20’s*, copiadas del inglés. En el español de América, en la construcción *la década de*..., aparece a veces en singular el artículo que acompaña al cardinal: *la década del treinta*, en lugar de *la década de los treinta*, construcción esta última más habitual y recomendable.

Además, el artículo sobre [apóstrofo](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=wV8heEHVFD64FHx2Ng) aborda el caso de ⓧ *los '80*:

> *apóstrofo*. Signo ortográfico auxiliar en forma de coma alta (’), que apenas se usa en el español actual.
>
> 3. Hay que evitar los siguientes usos del apóstrofo, ajenos al español, y que se deben al influjo del inglés:
>
> a) Cuando aparece en sustitución de las dos primeras cifras de un año: ⓧ’82 por 1982. Si se desea hacer la abreviación, lo que es frecuente en la expresión de acontecimientos relevantes celebrados en ciertos años, no debe utilizarse el apóstrofo: ⓧBarcelona ’92 (Juegos Olímpicos). Basta con las dos últimas cifras del año, que pueden unirse o no con guion a la palabra precedente: Barcelona 92 o Barcelona-92.

Resumiendo, **sí** es correcto utilizar:

- *los años ochenta*
- *la década de los ochenta*
- *los ochenta*

Pero **no** es correcto usar:

- ⓧ *los ochentas*
- ⓧ *los 80s*
- ⓧ *los 80's*
- ⓧ *los '80*

Comment: ¿Y la primera pregunta?  ¿Es correcto usarlo [los '80]?

Comment: @aparente001 no lo responde el DPD explícitamente, pero yo entiendo que no, pues no es más que una variación de _80's_ poniendo la comilla delante. Es decir, las [comillas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=SSTAZ5sDyD6h59vijX) no se usan para denotar años.

Comment: Fedorqui, no te entendí del todo tu comentario, pero para aclarar, creo que lo que escribió Rodrigo es un *apóstrofe*, no una *comilla.*

Comment: @aparente001 tienes razón, gracias. Buscando un poco encontré la referencia del DPD al respecto. Por cierto, nótese que es un _apóstrof**o**_, [_apóstrofe_](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=MORBQERXID6xT5y4DQ) con _e_ es una figura retórica.

Comment: Gracias, ajá, un *faux ami* (por cierto, ¿cómo se dice en español?).  // No entiendo "DPD".

Comment: @aparente001 ¿[*falso amigo*](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=false%20friend)? DPD es el [Diccionario panhispánico de dudas](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/dpd), una de las joyas de la corona de la RAE.